# In Perl, how can I generate all possible combinations of a list?

Tags: arrays, perl, combinations, combinatorics

I have a file with a list, and a need to make a file that compares each line to the other. for example, my file has this:

```
AAA  
BBB  
CCC  
DDD  
EEE
```

I would like the final list to look like this:

```
AAA  BBB  
AAA  CCC  
AAA  DDD  
AAA  EEE  
BBB  CCC  
BBB  DDD  
BBB  EEE  
CCC  DDD  
CCC  EEE  
DDD  EEE
```

I am trying to do this in Perl, for this first time and am having a little trouble. I do know that you need to make an array, and then split it, but after that I am having some trouble.

Comment: Please post your so far code.

Answer (score 30):

Use [Algorithm::Combinatorics](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Combinatorics). The iterator based approach is preferable to generating everything at once.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(combinations);

my $strings = [qw(AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE)];

my $iter = combinations($strings, 2);

while (my $c = $iter->next) {
    print "@$c\n";
}
```

Output:

```
AAA BBB
AAA CCC
AAA DDD
AAA EEE
BBB CCC
BBB DDD
BBB EEE
CCC DDD
CCC EEE
DDD EEE
```

Answer (score 9):

It is straightforward to write this using recursion.

This code example demonstrates.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $strings = [qw(AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE)];

sub combine;

print "@$_\n" for combine $strings, 5;

sub combine {

  my ($list, $n) = @_;
  die "Insufficient list members" if $n > @$list;

  return map [$_], @$list if $n <= 1;

  my @comb;

  for my $i (0 .. $#$list) {
    my @rest = @$list;
    my $val  = splice @rest, $i, 1;
    push @comb, [$val, @$_] for combine \@rest, $n-1;
  }

  return @comb;
}
```

---

**Edit**

My apologies - I was generating permutations instead of *combinations*.

This code is correct.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $strings = [qw(AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE)];

sub combine;

print "@$_\n" for combine $strings, 2;

sub combine {

  my ($list, $n) = @_;
  die "Insufficient list members" if $n > @$list;

  return map [$_], @$list if $n <= 1;

  my @comb;

  for (my $i = 0; $i+$n <= @$list; ++$i) {
    my $val  = $list->[$i];
    my @rest = @$list[$i+1..$#$list];
    push @comb, [$val, @$_] for combine \@rest, $n-1;
  }

  return @comb;
}
```

**output**

```
AAA BBB
AAA CCC
AAA DDD
AAA EEE
BBB CCC
BBB DDD
BBB EEE
CCC DDD
CCC EEE
DDD EEE
```

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [Math::Combinatorics](http://search.cpan.org/~allenday/Math-Combinatorics-0.09/lib/Math/Combinatorics.pm) - Perform combinations and permutations on lists

example copying from the CPAN:

```
use Math::Combinatorics;

  my @n = qw(a b c);
  my $combinat = Math::Combinatorics->new(count => 2,
                                          data => [@n],
                                         );

  print "combinations of 2 from: ".join(" ",@n)."\n";
  print "------------------------".("--" x scalar(@n))."\n";
  while(my @combo = $combinat->next_combination){
    print join(' ', @combo)."\n";
  }

  print "\n";

  print "permutations of 3 from: ".join(" ",@n)."\n";
  print "------------------------".("--" x scalar(@n))."\n";
  while(my @permu = $combinat->next_permutation){
    print join(' ', @permu)."\n";
  }

  output:
combinations of 2 from: a b c
  ------------------------------
  a b
  a c
  b c

  permutations of 3 from: a b c
  ------------------------------
  a b c
  a c b
  b a c
  b c a
  c a b
  c b a
```

Comment: Why don't you use the example data from the question?

Answer (score 2):

I benchmarked the following Perl modules:

1. [Math::Combinatorics](http://search.cpan.org/~allenday/Math-Combinatorics-0.09/lib/Math/Combinatorics.pm)
2. [Algorithm::Combinatorics](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Combinatorics)
3. [Cmb](https://github.com/FrauBSD/pkgcenter/tree/master/depend/libcmb)

Benchmark consisted of doing what the OP asked, combinations of 2 items, but ramping the set of words up to 10,000 instead of just the original 5 requested (AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE).

### Test script for Math::Combinatorics

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Math::Combinatorics;
my $strings = [qw(AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE) x 2000];
my $iter = new Math::Combinatorics (count => 2, data => $strings);
while (my @c = $iter->next_combination) {
    print "@c\n";
}
```

This produced ~53,479 combinations per-second.

### Test script for Algorithm::Combinatorics

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(combinations);
my $strings = [qw(AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE) x 2000];
my $iter = combinations($strings, 2);
while (my $c = $iter->next) {
    print "@$c\n";
}
```

This produced ~861,982 combinations per-second.

### Test script for Cmb

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Cmb;
my $strings = [qw(AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE) x 2000];
my $cmb = new Cmb { size_min => 2, size_max => 2 };
$cmb->cmb_callback($#$strings + 1, $strings, sub {
    print "@_\n";
    return 0;
});
```

This produced ~2,940,882 combinations per-second.

But if you just need to print the combinations, Cmb can actually do that even faster than the above.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Cmb;
my $strings = [qw(AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE) x 2000];
my $cmb = new Cmb { size_min => 2, size_max => 2 };
$cmb->cmb($#$strings + 1, $strings);
```

This produced ~3,333,000 combinations per-second.

Benchmarks were performed using [dpv](https://github.com/FrauBSD/pkgcenter/tree/master/depend/dpv) on CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core) under kernel 3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64 using Perl 5.16.3 on an Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hack using [`glob`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html):

```
my @list = qw(AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE);

for my $i (0..$#list-1) {
    print join "\n", glob sprintf "{'$list[$i] '}{%s}",
          join ",", @list[$i+1..$#list];
    print "\n";
}
```

The output:

```
AAA BBB
AAA CCC
AAA DDD
AAA EEE
BBB CCC
BBB DDD
BBB EEE
CCC DDD
CCC EEE
DDD EEE
```

P.S. you may want to use [`Text::Glob::Expand`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Glob::Expand) or [`String::Glob::Permute`](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Glob::Permute) modules instead of plain `glob()` to avoid the caveat of matching files in the current working directory.

Comment: The glob trick should always be accompanied by the various caveats for when it fails.

Answer (score 0):

1. take first string
2. iterate over array from next position to end

   1. attach next string to original string
3. take next string and go back to step 2

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my @in = qw(AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE);
my @list;
while(my $first = shift @in) {
    last unless @in;
    my $rest = join',',@in;
    push @list, glob("{$first}{$rest}");
}
dump @list;
```

**output:**

```
(
  "AAABBB",
  "AAACCC",
  "AAADDD",
  "AAAEEE",
  "BBBCCC",
  "BBBDDD",
  "BBBEEE",
  "CCCDDD",
  "CCCEEE",
  "DDDEEE",
)
```

Comment: The glob trick should always be accompanied by the various caveats for when it fails.

Comment: @daxim: Do you mean the "side-effect" of matching files in the current working directory? If so, isn't this perfectly safe since he's not using `?`, `[]` or `*`?

Comment: All of that. I am annoyed now, the caveats should be clearly laid out as part of the answer, not rhetoric questions attached as a comment with low visibility. It's not a "side-effect", it really happens, modalising the word is wrong. It's not safe: obviously the user provided made-up/anonymised data in the question and will be in for a bad surprise under real world conditions. SO answers should strive to not set people up for failure, they should be always aware of subtleties and risks; given that, I have now downvoted this answer to give M42 an incentive to improve it. -- continued:

Comment: I recommend Text::Glob::Expand or String::Glob::Permute over plain glob, if only that the documentation is better and they do the manipulation on in-memory data structures, not influenced by external factors like the shell or what's in the current directory.

Comment: @daxim: That's a good point. Quoting side-effect was meant as a joke though: I agree that SO isn't the best place to be teaching these kinds of tricks.