# how to save combinations generated by (Algorithm::Combinatorics) in an array of array

Tags: perl

I have an array (@strings) including some words. I want to generate all possible combinations and save the results in a data structure like array of array. I found a post "[In Perl, how can I generate all possible combinations of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299961/in-perl-how-can-i-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list)" but I could not save it in an array of array

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(combinations);

print join("\t", @strings),"\n";
```

AAA  BBB  CCC   DDD   EEE

```
my $iter = combinations(\@strings, 2);
while (my $c = $iter->next) {
    print "@$c\n";
}
```

I tried:

```
my @a;
while (my $c = $iter->next) {
    push @a, @$c;
    }
```

Comment: the `$c` is an array ref, so: `push @arr,$c;`

Comment: FYI, if you have a large number of words, you'll eat up a lot of memory storing all of the combinations in an array. That's exactly why modules like this usually provide iterators, so you can step through the results without having to store them all in memory. What exactly are you doing that requires you to store all the combinations in an array?

Comment: each combination including two elements would be two inputs for an script. in order to run all in parallel I thought to save each combination into one element of a new array

Comment: @EpiMan No need to save the combinations, just start the script as you iterate. Primitive example: `while (my $c = $iter->next) { system("/path/to/script @$c &"); }`

Answer (score 2):

```
use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw( combinations );
use Parallel::ForkManager    qw( );

use constant MAX_WORKERS => 10;

my @strings = ...;

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(MAX_WORKERS);
my $iter = combinations(\@strings, 2);

while (my $c = $iter->next) {
   my $pid = $pm->start and next;

   exec('program', @$c)
      or die("Can't execute child: $!\n");
}
```